# How to add tags to my sandbox module?

Tags: version-control

I 'm working on a sandbox module, which is [text_or_user_reference field](http://drupal.org/sandbox/mohit_rocks/1978818).

To release the module, I have to create a branch of the module i.e 7.x-1.0

Since beginning of the module development I was not aware with this thing, so I was working on master branch.

Now I have to add the tags to create the branch. To create the tags I followed [this](http://drupal.org/node/1066342) guide on drupal.org

These are the commands to push and create the tags:

> git tag 7.x-1.0
>
> git push --tags
>
> git push origin tag 7.x-1.0

I have applied all the commands, but I am not able to see whether tags are created or not.

My problems:

- How to check whether tags are created or not ?
- Do I have to seperately assign to tags to each file like `.module` file, `.install` file etc.
- When I go to Edit of the project and select the dropdown **version to work from** it doesn't show the tags/version I created i.e. 7.x-1.0

  Consider this command:

  > git branch -v

  What should I expect as a result after I run it? The list of all the files of current branch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In *git*, the terms "branch" and "tag" always applies to the whole repository, not to the individual files.  A branch denote is a *series* of commits (so you always use an "x" instead of specific version number for a branch). A tag is a label for a *specific version*, so you specify the version number (e.g. `1.0` for the first released version, `1.1` for the next, and so on.)

The command `git branch -v` will give a verbose listing of the current head.  It should, in the case of Drupal 7, start with a line `* 7.x-1.x`.  If it says `master` on the first line, you've not set things up right.

Before adding tags, you need to get your project on a `7.x-1.x` *branch*.  In your local repository, do the following to checkout branch `7.x-1.x` and delete branch `master`, and push those changes to the remote:

```
git checkout -b 7.x-1.x
git branch -d master
git branch -v
git push origin 7.x-1.x
git push origin :master
```

After you've made sure the branch is `7.x-1.x`, you can go ahead and add a tag to your release.

You can use the commands you refer to, to tag.  To see all the tag(s) in the local repository:

```
git tag
```

After pushing to the remote, if you've done this correctly, you should be able to click on the *Version control* tab and find the `7.x-1-x` branch in the *Version to work from:* pull-down menu.  If you retain the `master` branch, make sure that you make the `7.x-1.x` branch the default.

Comment: Do i have to assign tags to each file manually? as i can find that only one file has tags added and this file is README.txt file

Comment: Shall i give the name like 7.x-1.0 or 7.x-1.X

Comment: So first i have to create a branch right ?

Comment: last question..do i have to delete the master branch? because it is better if we keep it

Comment: No - but the master branch is confusing in the context of a Drupal release, since ir may apply to any version of Drupal.